# hosting MVC3 in subdirectory not work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, razor

i have a subdomain on site to test application [MVC3 razor]. when i upload the project i got that the nothing works instead of home page. can anyone show me if i miss something.

like

mydomain.com/nm > nm is subfolder

nm is work and everthing else not suppose mydomain.com/nm/home/index not work.

can someone show me the way i can use to deploy my application in subdirectory

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run a standalone application in a subdirectory you need to create a virtual application on your IIS.

If you just upload the app to a subdirectory in an existing MVC application it will share the application pool, routing and web.config.